# Bootstrap 'row' class is not working with CDN or downloaded version

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do some simple prototyping with an HTML page and bootstrap. I first tried using the CDN then switched to the local version, and neither time was I able to get the 'row' class to work properly; the content still stacks over each other rather than next to each other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stoodigo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <ul id="list-1">
            <li id="listItem-1">
              <input id="input-1" /><button class="addBtn"></button><button class="divertBtn"></button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting the elements to align next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CDN from the docs I was able to get the columns to create the way you intended. Please see my examples below.

This is a link to the documentation explaining columns and the grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

Example from docs,

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example using your HTML but the only change is I added the CDN from the Bootstrap docs which you can find [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

**CDN**

*JS*

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

*CSS*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stoodigo</title>
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <ul id="list-1">
            <li id="listItem-1">
              <input id="input-1" /><button class="addBtn"></button><button class="divertBtn"></button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```